# Suppose $\sum a_nz^n$ has a radius of convergence R and let C be the circle {$z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| = R$} Prove or disprove the following:

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, power-series, absolute-convergence

Suppose $\sum a_nz^n$ has a radius of convergence R and let C be the circle {$z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| = R$} Prove or disprove the following:

a) If $\sum a_nz^n$ converges at some point on C then it converges everywhere on C

b) If $\sum a_nz^n$ converges absolutely at some point on C then it converges absolutely everywhere on C

c) If $\sum a_nz^n$ converges at every point on C, except possibly one, then it converges  absolutely everywhere on C (hint: the series $\sum z^n/n$)

I believe that a) and b) are true.
For a) I  have

There exists $M\geq 0$ such that $|a_nz_0^n| \leq M$, then if $|z|<|z_0|$,
$|a_nz^n| = |a_nz_0|^n|\frac{z}{z_0}|^n \leq M |\frac{z}{z_0}|^n$.
Comparing this to a convergent geometric we have it is convergent everywhere.

For b) it seems like it's the same proof as part a) and c) I am lost.

Comment: You couldn't use the hint for $c$? $\sum \frac 1n$ is not convergent, how about at other $z$ with $|z| = 1$? The argument for $a$ doesn't work because $|z| = |z_0|$ , not $<$.

Comment: Note that a) and b) are about points on the boundary of the circle and not inside it. $
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{z^n }}{n}}$ converges at $-1 \in C$ but does it converge at all the other points of $C$?

Comment: B is true since it is a condition on the absolute value of the coefficients so doesn't depend on the argument

Comment: @TeresaLisbon, i see that it's true but how do i go about proving it. Would I use a ratio test to show that the lim = |z|

Comment: @pop No, you will have to decompose $z = e^{i \theta}$ and think about some kind of known series.